# JQuery: setting radio button in group based on if

Tags: jquery

This SHOULD be simple, I just know it should.

Basically, I have the code below in the error function of an $.ajax call. The call itself works. The call happens when the value of a radiobutton group goes from true to false or vice versa. If the error gets hit, I want to reset it to the previous value. What have I got wrong?

```
if ($("input[name='enableEmail']:checked").val() == "true") {
                $("input[name='enableEmail'][value='false']").attr("checked", true);
            }
            else {
                $("input[name='enableEmail'][value='true']").attr("checked", true);                    
            }
```

**EDIT** Apparently the question wasn't clear enough. I have two radio buttons in a group: On and Off. If user toggles from Off to On, a $.ajax call happens. If an error happens in the $.ajax call, I want to set the radio button back to Off. If the user toggles On to Off, I want it to go back to On in the event of an error

Comment: What is the 'else' even doing here?

Comment: I think I'm missing something obvious; but...what is that you're trying to do..?

Comment: As slandau said, the else seems redundant, however, this appears to work.  What exactly is happening when it fires?  http://jsfiddle.net/w4aXs/

Comment: Edited question to hopefully be more clear. Nothing is happening right now. The error is thrown and the code seems to go through but the radio button doesn't change.

Comment: Nevermind, window was cached, didnt' see lastest comment.

Comment: Please show your HTML.  Your code should work, see: http://jsfiddle.net/djkMd/

Comment: Turns out the code is fine. I'm using jQuery UI and needed to call .buttonset("refresh"). Sorry for the time waster. I can't answer my own question for some bizarre rule here, so I guess if someone wants to repost this I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if you are using jQuery UI and need to call .buttonset("refresh"). :-)

HTML and other contextual code would be a big help.  Lacking that, have you tried using firebug or something along those lines to do some sanity checks on values and jQuery selectors by outputting to the console?

```
if ($("input[name='enableEmail']:checked").val() == "true") {
    console.log("Got here 1: " + $("input[name='enableEmail'][value='false']").attr("checked"));
    $("input[name='enableEmail'][value='false']").attr("checked", true);
}
else {
    console.log("Got here 2: " + $("input[name='enableEmail'][value='true']").attr("checked"));
    $("input[name='enableEmail'][value='true']").attr("checked", true);                    
}
```

Comment: Quite :). And I didn't know about the console log stuff, that's handy info.

Comment: Firebug and the console are invaluable for javascript debugging.  But do it in a way that allows you to leave your console.log statements in the code for browsers that don't support it.  The quick and dirty way is `window.console && console.log
&& console.log( 'message' );`.  A google search on "console.log errors" will give more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Error for ajax is called when the ajax requests **fails**. Are you sure such an error occurs  and not some error in logic that returns undesired results ?

Seems to work for me ... http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zGvRR/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `runat="server"` on the input tags for the radio buttons. Remove `runat` tag and try. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.attr("checked", "checked");
```

Try that. It's not a boolean value.